# How to call and display

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

firstly, i want to build navigator drawer. i have already call text from firebase but my problem is how to display in nav_header. i dont know how to explain in specific. I want key in first name and last name but i dont know where to call class .i try show my code.

This how i call string from firebase but now i try to display in navigator bar

```
 userDatabase = new UserDatabase();

    reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member").child(userid);
    reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserDatabase user = snap.getValue(UserDatabase.class);
                txvName.setText(""+user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName());
                txvAdd.setText(""+user.getAddress1()+" "+user.getAddress2()+" "+user.getAddress3());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

that so many xml and that only one of class is sidemenu.class . I dont know where to put the code in sidemenu.class

Comment: Use it in your activity's `onCreate` which contains the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call inside activity which contains Navigation drawer
and add menu item like this

```
final Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.add(user.getFirstName()+" "+user.getLastName());
```